# htaccess directory to file issue

Tags: .htaccess

I have been racking my brains for a few hours with this.

I wish to use **www.mrsmith.com/cars/**

however the actual page is in a different directory based at **www.mrsmith.com/pagebuilder/carinformation.php**

How do I do an apache rewrite (htaccess) so that the directory www.mrsmith.com/cars/ forwards to  www.mrsmith.com/pagebuilder/carsinformation.php

And more importantly keeps with the uri of www.mrsmith.com/cars

Answer (score 1):

In the htaccess file in your **document root** add these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^ /pagebuilder/carinformation.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi Jon Thanks, unfortunately I cant add a htaccess file to the root, due to an old cms system going haywire if I add htaccess, I can only add htaccess file to the directory www.mrsmith.com/cars/

Comment: Then add `RewriteBase /` and remove the cars bit, see edited answer

Comment: Thanks jon for the quick reply, unfortunately i know get a 403 Forbidden error, recarding /cars/